# What does this expression mean in JavaScript : if ($(element).attr('id') in special_validations)

Tags: javascript

I don´t understand the key word 'in'.

it´s a conditional builder?

This is the context:

```
if ($(element).attr('id') in special_validations)
            {
                var validation = special_validations[$(element).attr('id')]($(element).val());
                if (validation == true && typeof validation == 'boolean')
                    $(element).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
                else
                {
                    total_errors++;
                    $(element).parent().addClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
                    if (typeof validation == 'string')
                        $('<label class="control-label" for="'+$(element).attr('id')+'">'+validation+'</label>').insertAfter(element);
                    else
                        $('<label class="control-label" for="'+$(element).attr('id')+'">Formato no válido</label>').insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) keyword checks if a certain key is in an object. Note that this checks the key, not the value.

So, your example checks if the element's ID is a key in the `special_validations` object.

Answer (score -1):

### `in` a Conditional test

`in` represents something **inside** of something else. So we can use it as a conditional test to **check** if something is `in` something else.

In an `Object`, we could check if a **property name** exists inside it:

```
var my_object = {first:'a',second:'b',third:'c',fourth:'d'}

console.log( 'first' in my_object ) // returns true
console.log( 'me' in my_object ) // returns false
```

In an `Array`, we could check if a key exists inside it:

This **array** has five **keys** `in` it.

```
var my_array = [ 'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e' ]
```

Each element can then be referenced later with a numeric **key** like so:

```
my_array[0] = 'a'
my_array[1] = 'b'
my_array[2] = 'c'
my_array[3] = 'd'
my_array[4] = 'e'

console.log( 0 in my_array ) // returns true
console.log( 1 in my_array ) // returns true
console.log( 2 in my_array ) // returns true
console.log( 3 in my_array ) // returns true
console.log( 4 in my_array ) // returns true
console.log( 5 in my_array ) // returns false
```

> So the `in` operator refers to the conditionality of an `Object`
>   containing a certain **property name**.

---

### `in` looping Arrays with numeric keys

Lets say you have an **array** like so:

```
var my_array = [ 'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' , 'e' ]
```

You can use a for loop to iterate through each of these:

```
for(var key=0; key<my_array.length; key++){
    var this_element = my_array[key]
}
```

But you can also do this with the `in` operator:

```
for(var key in my_array){
    var this_element = my_array[key]
}
```

> So the `in` operator refers to each **key** inside of an `Array`.

---

### `in` looping Objects with NON-numeric keys

The `in` operator is commonly used with a `for` loop through `Object` **property names** in JavaScript.

This is especially useful for `Objects` that have **properties**, which are somewhat treated like `Array` **values**.

A lot of times you many not be sure how many **properties** exist inside of your **object** or even what the **property names** are.

For example, this is a typical **Object**:

```
var my_object = {first:'a',second:'b',third:'c',fourth:'d'}
```

Each **property** can then be referred to with their **property name**, like so:

```
my_object['first']  = 'a'
my_object['second'] = 'b'
my_object['third']  = 'c'
my_object['fourth'] = 'd'
```

So here, we see that the **properties** are not defined with simple integer numbers like an `Array`.  Therefore we **must** use the `in` operator to walk us through the `Object` **properties**.

`Object` **properties** rarely have numeric **keys** like JavaScript `Arrays` do. So there is no way to conduct a traditional numeric `for` loop.

So instead of defining a `for` loop traditionally with definite numeric bounds, you use `in` to write the following without including any definite bounds into the `for` loop parameters, like so:

```
for(var element in my_array){}
```

> So the `in` operator refers to each **property name** of an `Object`.

---

### Dangers of using `in` with `for`

Objects have inherent properties.

For example, an `Array` is a type of `Object` and all `Arrays` have the `length` property in their **object prototype**.

Just by defining an empty object, there are certain properties that come with it. A `for` loop using `in` will iterate over these undesired properties and '*could*' break your code.

So, even in an empty `Array`:

```
console.log( 'length' in new Array() ) // returns true
```

This same principle may cause a `for` loop to iterate over undesired **properties**, depending on your web-browser and version.

Comment: *"So the JavaScript operator `in` refers to each element inside of an array."* Uhm what? Can you elaborate on that? *"[...] which are somewhat treated like array elements [...]"*: this is just confusing. *"That is an object like an array"* What's an example of an object that is *not* like an array? Objects are simply key-value stores. Arrays are a specialized version of key-value stores where keys are numeric. Saying that an object is "like an array" is confusing at best and simply wrong at worst.

Comment: *"So the in operator refers to each element inside of an array."* Not exactly true. `for/in` iterates over the object's **property names**. If you have an array it means it iterates over the **indexes** of the array. You can then use that index to refer to the corresponding element. But again, you are describing the `for/in` loop, which has nothing to do with the `in` operator (which is what the question is about).